# How to write Quick/Nimble test cases for testing swift segues without storyboard

Tags: swift, unit-testing, segue, quick-nimble

I'm new to writing nimble test cases and having problems writing quick/nimble test cases for checking swift segues without storyboard

Comment: Hey Steven, welcome to the site! I think there’s a few things here that make this question hard to answer. Largely, it’s that it’s because this question falls in the intersection of two niches (those who use nimble+quick instead of vanilla XCTest, and those who don’t use storyboards), thus fewer people would be qualified to answer. Luckily, it think that can be remedied easily, just by removing the details about Nimble and Quick. Nimbler is just a matched library that improves the readability of assertions, and Quick is just a library to help better organize test code. Neither one does …

Comment: … anything special that couldn’t be done right in XCTest (that’s clearly the case, because both of them are built on top of XCTest). Secondly, I don’t know enough about UIKit segues, to answer this, but: are they fundamentally different if they’re not created via storyboards? Or are storyboards just one mechanism for constructing segues, which you otherwise could have written yourself (I suspect this is the case). If it’s the latter, then perhaps it’ll help to remove the detail about not using storyboards, because it wouldn’t be relevant.

Comment: Lastly, it would help to have at least a tiny sample demonstrating the kind of thing you’re trying to test, otherwise the answers would just be a combination of mind reading and guesswork.